# How to insert number values into cassandra

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver, cassandra-3.0, dbeaver

I'm try to insert number values at Cassandra using dbeaver and datasax jdbc driver. But just String and Date values are inserted.

Create table:

```
CREATE TABLE TEST_DATA (
  my_key text
 ,evt_date TIMESTAMP
 ,object_id text
 ,lat FLOAT
 ,lng FLOAT
 ,warn SMALLINT
 ,PRIMARY KEY( my_key,evt_date)
)
WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (evt_date desc);
```

Inserting data:

```
INSERT INTO TEST_DATA (my_key, evt_date, object_id, lat, lng, warn)
values ('k001', '2018-02-07 14:07:00', 'CAR001', 20.683940, -88.567740, 2);
```

selecting data:

```
SELECT * FROM TEST_DATA;
```

[image]

Numbers doesn't appears.

There are another open source tools to manipulate cassandra?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `cqlsh` that comes together with Cassandra:

```
cqlsh:test> INSERT INTO TEST_DATA (my_key, evt_date, object_id, lat, lng, warn)
     values ('k001', '2018-02-07 14:07:00', 'CAR001', 20.683940, -88.567740, 2);

cqlsh:test> select * from test_data;

my_key | evt_date                        | lat      | lng       | object_id | warn
-------+---------------------------------+----------+-----------+-----------+------
  k001 | 2018-02-07 13:07:00.000000+0000 | 20.68394 | -88.56774 |    CAR001 |    2
```

Answer (score 1):

So... the problem not happen with cassandra, was DBeaver (community version 4.0.7)

The numbers values are inserted but DBeaver doesn't show them.

Using DbSchema tool to execute the SELECT I can see the data.

[image]